# Open desktop application by command without using Sikuli Library - Robot Framework

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, sikuli

Folks,

I searched the Sikuli library (Robot Framework), but I didn't find what I needed.
The documentation is http://rainmanwy.github.io/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/doc/SikuliLibrary.html#Open%20Application.

Is there any way, via Robot Framework, Sikuli library (or some other) that I can open a desktop application other than by image?
This would generate a lower cost in running the tests.

Awaiting!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean: Open an application (.exe) when the python file gets ran?

Comment: To run a desktop application other than image use ```exec``` or ```from os import execv``` then ```execv()```

Comment: But that would be in .py (python) file, correct?
Can I run the command in .robot file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start an application - you can use Process library (built-in into Robot Framework). There are 3 different sort of keywords - `Run Process` and `Start Process`. See https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html for more details.

However, you would still need some extra libraries (like Sikuli) to interact with given app.

Comment: Rasjani, very thanks!! I I got it!! But, the last question: How do i close a program using this library (Process library)? I searched and i found a keyword that calls "Terminate All Processes" and "Terminate Process", but they don't close the program...  Do you know something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I closed this question and opened a new. It's better..

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SikuliLibrary   mode=NEW


*** Variables ***
${APP_PATH}     C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe

*** Test Cases ***
TC 024971 Start Uninstall
    Start Sikuli Process
    Add Image Path      F:\Images
    Open Application    ${APP_PATH}
```